# The space of periodizable tempered distribution

Tags: operator-theory, generalized-functions, periodic-functions, tempered-distributions

The periodization operator $\mathrm{Per}$ is defined for a Schwartz function $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ as
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Per} \{ \varphi \} (x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \varphi( x - n ), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.  \tag{1}
\end{equation}
The sum in (1) is of course well-defined pointwise due to the rapid decay of $\varphi$ and we then have that $\mathrm{Per}\{\varphi\}$ is an infinitely smooth $1$-periodic function. More generally, it is possible to define the periodization operator $\mathrm{Per}$ over rapidly decaying distributions $\mathcal{O}_{C}'(\mathbb{R})$ (see for instance [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/3/2/299) for details). We then have
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Per} : \mathcal{O}_{C}'(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{T}) \tag{2}
\end{equation}
continuously, the latter space being the space of $1$-periodic distributions.

**Question:** Can we define a proper subspace of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ that maximally extends the periodization in a precise sense? That is, a space on which the periodization is well-defined, with a natural topology that makes the periodization continuous, with good reasons for its "maximality"?

Comment: Would this just be the set of functions $\{f: \forall x\in\Bbb{R}, \sum\limits_{n\in\Bbb{Z}} f(x-n)<\infty\}$?

Comment: @fierydemon First I also want to include generalized functions with no pointwise definition (e.g., the Dirac comb $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\delta(\cdot - n)$. But even with well-defined pointwise values, it is not obvious to me what is a good function space to deal with. In your suggestion, what is the meaning of the infinite sum? Pointwise convergence for each $x$? Where is the function $f$? These are typically the questions I am facing.